# How to know if a winform launch takes more than 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, process

I have a situation that i have to create some mechanism using coding in c#-Winform such that when i launch any particular winform if it takes more than specified seconds to get launch (lets say 10 seconds) then i have to display a loader (ajax loader type of thing) until i do not get the form display completely. (this form takes lot of times as it displays data after lot of calculations, so i wish to display some loader meanwhile).

`I successfully designed the circle like loader`. Now the problem is :

(1.) How to know if the form launch takes more than `10 seconds` ? So that i launch loader.

(2.) The other problem is i have to make it work for all forms in common (because the project is very big so instead of writing the code of loader for every individual form, i wish to know any way to achieve this functionality globally that if any currently launched form takes more then 10 seconds then it display loader (and should work for all forms on launch if they takes more than 10 seconds with-out writing the code to display on each individual form) and stops loader as form appears.

**How to achieve these two functionalities ?**

Comment: Why wait ten seconds? What if the time taken is 10.5s. As a user I have been waiting for a form to complete and only for 0.5s I get an indication that it takes a while. Can't you show a loader based on the number of calculations you need to do? Also, where is the heavy work done, in the constructor? OnLoad? Please show so code and what you've come up so far (Timers?)

Comment: I don't know why you have bothered with this. The standard idiom is to display a *busy* cursor. Surely you have seen it. You just display it before doing the loading operation, and once the load is done, the busy cursor will go away automatically. Or, you can just display your little loading animation, perform the task, and remove the loading animation when it's done. It is not worth it trying to write time-detection code.

Comment: @CodyGray I am not allowed to code on every individual form ...because the project is very big. Is there any solution to achieve it globally instead of every form coding for loader ?

Comment: @user3085082 are the forms derived from a baseform, if so you might be able to do some of the magic there. Otherwise I can't see how to do it. If the size of the project makes people to no allow you to make improvements you obviously have bigger concerns.

Comment: Yes there is a Main winform which has various  childs in menu. On each menu click we have a child form launch which do calculation. So how this magic can be achieved on this mainwindow form?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this only if data is getting processed in a background thread, otherwise the form will be blocked and you cannot make any changes.

So, if it doing the work in a separate thread, try the following:

1. Make a base class and implement.

   1. a. Write a flag called DataLoaded or something.
   2. b. Write a flag called OutOfTime.
   3. c. Create dynamically the controls needed for the loader to be shown.
2. In base class use a Timer (there are 3 different ones, choose wisely) and in X seconds call a method.
3. When data is loaded if !OutOfTime set DataLoaded = true else close/hide the loader in case it has been shown on next step.
4. When Timer's event/method is called check if data is loaded, if not, it means that in those X seconds they were still processing, so show/call/display the loader.

Just an idea, probably wont work at first, but it's more or less what I would do :)

Comment: The Problem would be ..How to know if the data is loaded or not ? (I mean when to stop loader if it is lets say 10 second is set. I.E. I know when to start loader (when form is not loaded in 10 seconds) but how to know if form is loaded or not ?

Comment: True xD I knew it was too easy C:
Sorry, clicked enter by mistake.
How are you getting the data? 
Which framrwork are you using?
Give me a bit more detail.
How many forms do you have? Could be an easy solution, just to call a small this.DoneLoading() on every form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. (1) I have main window form.which has several menus which on respective click gives  individual form ( Form1  frm1 =new Form1(); frm.showdialog();  then this form futher popups another form after taking some data for calculation from user and do show calculation results on OK button click by poping up 3rd form and i do complex mathematical calculations at the OK click of this button which takes time and form popup very late) and there are 100 of form like this so my boss want a global solution for it rather then coding behind each form. I am using .NET 4.5

Comment: You didnt answer this question: are the calculations done in the same thread?
If they are in different threads, then the problem, as you stated it before, is that there is no easy way to know when the data is finished. It'd be something more complicated but not imposible. If calculations/data retrieval is done manually and hardcoded into each form, then you have no other option than hardcode the this.DoneLoading() . Which is the best way, since you could have more than one form open, it could lead to bugs.

Comment: its in same thread... But for loading i guess we will need another thread to be created

Comment: The oposite. You've got some work to do!! 
All the processing HAVE to be done in a background thread, that mean, it should run in parallel. Other wise the loading screen WONT load.
If you wrote this software, then you did it suboptimaly, and didnt think about this kind of stuff, and you need to take this as your mistake and fix it . If you didnt wrote this, then tell your boss it gonna take some time to fix and test , because the last developer didnt code this propetly.